# Installing NuGet package when dependency has been renamed

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to install the nuget package [Castle Transaction Services](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Castle.Services.Transaction/3.0.7.2007), which has a dependency on Rx-Core that cannot be resolved.

A search on "Rx" in the package manager GUI makes it seem like Rx-Core has been renamed to Rx-Main - is there any way to tell the package manager that, or to install Rx-Main and say "I know you think it's not going to work but I want to do this anyway" when installing Castle Transaction Services?

Does anyone know how to contribute to the transaction services project with an update of the NuGet package to reflect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the maintainer of the Rx packages, and they indeed shuffled their package structure, resulting in the removal of Rx-Core. But generally, it was not the best thing to do to remove the old package, and he agreed not to do this in the future.

There is no great way of telling NuGet to ignore that missing dependency. I suppose you could fool it by creating a dummy package with that name in your local feed. Hacky, but would work.

Your best bet is to notify the Castle Owners of the problem so they can fix it. You can do this by choosing 'Contact Owners' from the [NuGet package page](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Castle.Services.Transaction/3.0.7.2007). That package has 5 owners, so hopefully someone will react! :)

Some other Castle packages also have that missing dependency. e.g. Castle.Facilities.AutoTx