# Installing Castle.Transactions from NuGet doesn't produce a DLL

Tags: nuget, castle, windsor-facilities

A few days ago I installed the [`Castle.Facilities.AutoTx`](http://nuget.org/packages/Castle.Facilities.AutoTx) from NuGet which has a dependency on `Castle.Transactions`.  When I ran my application I got a `FileNotFoundException` trying to load a DLL from the Castle.Transactions folder.

Both of these packages have recently [been updated](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/castle-project-users/CLHTeZRy7qM/discussion) (27th June) and it seems like the update caused this problem.  There is a reply to that announcement from someone else saying that they have the same problem and they created a pull request to fix the issue which has not yet been accepted by the looks of things.

I have tried to go back and install an earlier version of Castle.Facilities.AutoTx from Nuget using the commands in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628689/download-old-version-of-package-with-nuget) but I ran into the problem detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383224/installing-nuget-package-when-dependency-has-been-renamed) in that the Rx-Core package had been renamed so that dependency couldn't be satisfied.

I have emailed Henrik Feldt who posted the 3.1 announcement and who also authors the Castle.Transactions package but I haven't had a response.  I would really like to get the AutoTx facility working in my application, can you suggest how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem few weeks ago. Unfortunately, since there is no other place to download it you'll have to fetch the source from GitHub, install Ruby, rake and other libraries needed for building it.
If you try to build it just using VS, you'll be missing an AssemblyInfo.cs file which is generated by rake build script. So you'll have to build using Rake, to get the AssemblyInfo.cs, then manually update assembly version in the file, and then build again in VisualStudio.
I could as well send you my assemblies, but it's safest for you to build yourself.

Temporarily, here's my [build of the library](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48707126/CastleTx.zip).

Comment: Thanks very much for the link to your build.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to get things working and I think it's because Castle has also been updated in the past few days (from 3.0 to 3.1).  This has turned into a bit of a dependency nightmare.  I have tried to use older versions of various packages to no avail so I think I'll just have to wait until AutoTx is updated to work with the new versions which is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this pull request before building it with rake..
https://github.com/haf/Castle.Transactions/pull/11

Answer (score 0):

Just installed the package by itself and it generated a dll.

```
Install-Package Castle.Transactions
```

Imagine that it's probably a newer version than the one Castle.Facilities.AutoTx requires uses but it still compiled in my case.